# Nested Firebase Firestore forEach promise queries

Tags: javascript, firebase, es6-promise, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase Cloud Firestore, however, I think this may be more of a JavaScript promise issue.

I have a collection called "students" which I am querying. For each found student I want to issue another query to find "parents" related by id.

For this, I have to nest a promise / foreach query and result inside another promise / foreach query and result.

Its currently executing the entire "students" promise/loop, returning from the function, then executing each of the "parents" promise/loops afterwards.

I want it to step through one found student, then execute all parents for that student, then go onto the next student, then return from the function.

```
  getStudents(grade) {
    let grade_part = this.getGrade(grade);
    var dbRef = db.collection("students");
    var dbQuery = dbRef.where('bb_current_grade', '==', grade_part);
    var dbPromise = dbQuery.get();
    var allStudents = [];
    return dbPromise.then(function(querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          console.log("student");
          var studentPlusParents = doc.data();
          studentPlusParents.parents = [];
          var dbRef = db.collection("parents");
          var dbQuery = dbRef.where('student_id', '==', doc.data().id);
          var dbPromise = dbQuery.get();
          dbPromise.then(function(querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(parentDoc => {
              console.log("Add parent");
              studentPlusParents.parents.push(parentDoc.data());
            });
          });
          //console.log(studentPlusParents);
          allStudents.push(studentPlusParents)
      });
      //console.log(allStudents);
      return Promise.all(allStudents);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Why do you need to change your approach?  Does your current implementation not work?

Comment: The inner promise, which needs to look up parents and insert them into an array, resolves after the outer promise and main function resolve. So the returned array does not include the results of the inner promise.

Comment: Just push *every* single promise that's not being returned into another chain somehow into an array, then Promise.all() on that array.  No need to collect them separately.  You're kind of doing that now.

Comment: I am not sure what to say. I am at the limit of my understanding when it comes to working with promises. I did try a version of that. No matter what I do the inner promises do not begin executing until the entire outer foreach has completed. For instance "student" is printed a full 40 times, then "parent" is printed 80 times. I want it to print one student, then two parents, one student, then two parents, etc...

Comment: It seems to me that it doesn't matter what's printed at the console, and it matters a whole lot more that all the work that needs to be done gets done before the function cleans up.

Comment: Of course. I was trying to use the print statements to demonstrate that is not happening. What I want is for studentPlusParents.parents to get populated before the function returns  studentPlusParents to the caller.  This is not happening. When  studentPlusParents is returned  studentPlusParents.parents is empty, then the inner promise runs, but its too late as  studentPlusParents has already been returned.

Comment: I'm having the same problem here. Do you have the answer? @AdamG